# Qual a diferença entre :before para ::before

Tags: css3

Eu vi na documentação do css3 que a sintaxe nova é `::before`, mas eu sempre utilizei `:before`, existe diferença? Qual utilizar?

Comment: Basicamente os browsers antigos acabaram implementando fora do padrão, ai todo mundo acostumou com um `:` só, então era tolerado. O correto é conforme a resposta indicada.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda